# How to socksify apps in mac os

Tags: terminal, tunnel, socks

Is there an analog on mac os for http://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify ?
So that i can use it like on linux: socksify mongo ....

Comment: If you just want to do **ssh** via a socks proxy see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441921/macos-terminal-connect-to-ssh-using-socks-proxy

Answer (score 3):

I use [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) which can be configured to use a SOCKS proxy. It is available via Homebrew: `brew install proxychains-ng`.

Note there is a known limitation on 10.11+ that [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) prevents hooking of system binaries - see GitHub issue [#78](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues/78) - but it can be used with anything installed via Homebrew, as the binaries are in directories not affected by SIP. For example, to use (Homebrew installed & linked) `curl` through a Tor SOCKS proxy, your `.proxychains/proxychains.conf` would look like this:

```
[ProxyList]
socks5  127.0.0.1   9050
```

Check `curl` is Homebrew, not system version:

```
$ which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl
```

`proxychains4 curl http://ipinfo.io` then does this:

```
[proxychains] config file found: /Users/me/.proxychains/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.11
[proxychains] Dynamic chain  ...  127.0.0.1:9050  ...  52.58.99.202:80  ...  OK
{
  "ip": "194.71.109.74",
  "hostname": "tor.keff.org",
  "city": "Stockholm",
  "region": "Stockholm",
  "country": "SE",
  "loc": "59.3333,18.0500",
  "org": "AS41281 Scaling Networks AB",
  "postal": "173 11"
}
```

The README caveats explain why it does not work for everything, but it may be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

[ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com) might be what you are looking for. It allows you to socksify a command line program as well as a complete app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [TS-Warp](https://github.com/mezantrop/ts-warp), works natively on macOS, Linux, BSD. CLI and graphical apps, no SIP disabling, no KEXT installation on fresh macOS. It uses Firewall/NAT redirection instead of library preloading, so this plays the trick for macos with strict rules against preloaded libraries. Open-source.

https://github.com/mezantrop/ts-warp

Comment: Right now this reads like an ad. Can you improve your anwer by showing *how* the tool you recommend can be used to solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: @nohillside, improved the answer. The solution really does the trick.